# How INotifyPropertyChanged's PropertyChanged event get assigned?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, interface, inotifypropertychanged

I have following code and it is working fine.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Person person;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        person = new Person { Name = "ABC" };

        this.DataContext = person;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        person.Name = "XYZ";
    }
}

class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string name;

    public string Name
    { 
        get
        {
            return name;
        } 
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string strPropertyName)
    {
        if(null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, 
                            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName));
        }           
    } 
}
```

When I create the "person" object in the constructor of MainWindow, it will assign the value for "Name" property of person, that time PropertyChanged event is **NULL**.

If the same "person" class property "Name" assigned in Button_Click event, "PropertyChanged" event is **NOT NULL** and it is pointing to OnPropertyChanged.

My question is how "PropertyChanged" event is assigned to OnPropertyChanged method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really do your onpropertychanged as `var handler=PropertyChanged; if (null!=handler) handler(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName)` this will help you avoid a race condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WPF data-binding infrastructure will add a `PropertyChanged` handler when you set the object as a `DataContext`, in order to detect changes to your properties.
You can watch this happen by [setting a breakpoint](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/tracking-event-handler-registrations.html).

The `OnPropertyChanged` method that it points to is an internal WPF method, as you can see by inspecting the `Target` property of the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

The event will be null until something is subscribed to it.  By the time the button click event has happened, it has a subscriber (via the databinding system).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is contracting with SLaks answer. I'm confused which is correct?

Comment: @Syed: He isn't contradicting me; he's just providing less detail.  Until WPF subscribes to the event (when you bind to the model), it's `null`.

Comment: Another way to say it is my answer is more concise.  :)  Just kidding, SLaks answer explains it much better.